# How do i know a specific mime type for Android SAF?

Tags: android, mime-types, mime, storage-access-framework

I'd like to save a file of my custom type (let's say `.asf`) using Android Storage Access Framework's [ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file). What mime type should i pass to be supported at least default Android File manager and save on file storage? How about some more common extensions (eg. `.hex`)?

If i don't pass a `type` at all:

```
    fun saveFile(fromFile: File, fileName: String, mimeType: String, resultCode: Int) {
        inputFile = fromFile
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            if (mimeType.isNotEmpty()) {
                type = mimeType
            }
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName)
        }

        context.startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode)
    }
```

i'm getting:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] (has extras) }, , null)

Comment: `"*/*"` will suit you.

Answer (score -1):

### Update

### here I made a list for a better understanding

```
"MP3"   mime_type_is --> "audio/mpeg"
"MPGA"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/mpeg"
"M4A"   mime_type_is --> "audio/mp4"
"WAV"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/x-wav"
"AMR"   mime_type_is --> "audio/amr"
"AWB"   mime_type_is -->"audio/amr-wb"
"WMA"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/x-ms-wma"
"OGG"   mime_type_is --> "audio/ogg"
"OGG"   mime_type_is -->  "application/ogg"
"OGA"   mime_type_is -->  "application/ogg"
"AAC"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/aac"
"AAC"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/aac-adts"
 "MKA"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/x-matroska"
 "MID"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/midi"
 "MIDI"   mime_type_is --> "audio/midi"
 "XMF"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/midi"
 "RTTTL"   mime_type_is --> "audio/midi"
 "SMF"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/sp-midi"
 "IMY"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/imelody"
 "RTX"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/midi"
 "OTA"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/midi"
 "MXMF"   mime_type_is --> "audio/midi"
 "MPEG"   mime_type_is -->  "video/mpeg"
 "MPG"   mime_type_is --> "video/mpeg"
 "MP4"   mime_type_is --> "video/mp4"
 "M4V"   mime_type_is --> "video/mp4"
 "3GP"   mime_type_is -->  "video/3gpp"
 "3GPP"   mime_type_is -->  "video/3gpp"
 "3G2"   mime_type_is -->  "video/3gpp2"
 "3GPP2"   mime_type_is -->  "video/3gpp2"
 "MKV"   mime_type_is -->  "video/x-matroska"
 "WEBM"   mime_type_is -->  "video/webm"
 "TS"   mime_type_is -->  "video/mp2ts"
 "AVI"   mime_type_is -->  "video/avi"
 "WMV"   mime_type_is -->  "video/x-ms-wmv"
 "ASF"   mime_type_is -->  "video/x-ms-asf"
 "JPG"   mime_type_is --> "image/jpeg"
 "JPEG"   mime_type_is --> "image/jpeg"
 "GIF"   mime_type_is --> "image/gif"
 "PNG"   mime_type_is --> "image/png"
 "BMP"   mime_type_is --> "image/x-ms-bmp"
 "WBMP"   mime_type_is --> "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"
 "WEBP"   mime_type_is --> "image/webp"
"M3U"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/x-mpegurl"
"M3U"   mime_type_is -->  "application/x-mpegurl"
 "PLS"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/x-scpls"
 "WPL"   mime_type_is -->  "application/vnd.ms-wpl"
 "M3U8"   mime_type_is -->  "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"
 "M3U8"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/mpegurl"
 "M3U8"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/x-mpegurl"
 "FL"   mime_type_is -->  "application/x-android-drm-fl"
 "TXT"   mime_type_is -->  "text/plain"
 "HTM"   mime_type_is -->  "text/html"
 "HTML"   mime_type_is -->  "text/html"
 "PDF"   mime_type_is -->  "application/pdf"
 "DOC"   mime_type_is -->  "application/msword"
 "XLS"   mime_type_is -->  "application/vnd.ms-excel"
 "PPT"   mime_type_is --> "application/mspowerpoint"
 "FLAC"   mime_type_is -->  "audio/flac"
"ZIP"   mime_type_is -->  "application/zip"
"MPG"   mime_type_is -->  "video/mp2p"
"MPEG"   mime_type_is --> "video/mp2p"
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the core question of *"What mime type should i pass to be supported at least default Android File manager and save on file storage?"*